# from script to function

Tags: matlab, function

I was wondering if it is possible to make from a script a function.. To clarify, I have script in Matlab that calculate the seasonal premium of a commodity. As I have multiple commodities I made multiple scripts, where each script has the same coding for seasonality.

Now I want to transform the seasonality script into a function in order to have a clear mainscript!! (In order to calculate the seasonality, I had to use 200 lines)

The nice thing about the seasonality script is that I only have one input matrix and the output will be three matrices.

Or is it possible to execute a different script in a script without copying every line?

Comment: Are you familiar with creating functions in matlab? If yes, please explain what problem you are facing when making your script a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the function documentation, [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html). Here's an example:

```
function yourOutput = Seasonality(yourInput)
    yourOutput = yourInput + rand();  % Replace with your own code.
end
```

This code an be saved as a separate .m file, for clarity. To use it in your main script, simply use `Seasonality` as you would any other function. If it's still unclear, post your code as an edit to your question, I will take a look at it and tell you what to do.

Comment: Thanks @Fletch, I did not know it was this easy to transform a script into a function.. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two `MATLAB` scripts which look like this:

```
x = 42
y = 43

% do some complicated calculations with x and y and display the result
% ...
```

and

```
w = 1
z = 0

% do the calculations from the first script, but with the values w and z
% ...
```

you can simply create a function which accepts some input arguments and returns a result.
For our simple example, we could write:

```
function result = my_function(argument1, argument2)
   % do some complicated calculations with argument1 and argumen2
   % ...
   % assign result of the computation to the variable result
end
```

Now you can simply call `my_function` with any two input values you desire.
For more information please refer to http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/function.html - this will also explain how to return multiple result values.

Here's a quick sketch on how your function would work:

```
function [M1 M2 M3] = my_function(input_argument)    
    % do some complicated calculations for M1, M2, M3 based on input_argument
    % ...

    % assign some bogus values to M1, M2, M3 for demonstration
    M1 = [1, 2; 3, 4];
    M2 = [5, 6, 7; 8, 9, 10];
    M3 = [11, 12; 13, 14; 15, 16];
 end
```

Calling `my_function` in the interpreter would go like this:

```
>> [M1 M2 M3] = my_function(42)
M1 =
     1     2
     3     4
M2 =
     5     6     7
     8     9    10
M3 =
    11    12
    13    14
    15    16
```

Please note that the file in which `my_function` is saved should be named `my_function.m`.

Comment: Thank you for your response Tim

Comment: @user45266 If my response was helpful it would be nice of you to upvote :)